# netCore 3.0 Deploy Pipeline to Azure Error 500 AspNetCoreModule(V2) Handler: aspNetCore Error Cod: 0x00000000

Tags: azure, deployment, swagger, pipeline

Ran into an issue the other day that took me a few hours of head bashing to resolve.  I hope if someone is having a similar issue I can save them some time.   I have a new API i'm building and everything working as expected locally.  Setup my dev and staging environments in azure then went about setting up my build and release pipelines.  All of that is pretty straight forward as it's just a bunch of button clicking with a little yaml editing.

after the deploy I try to hit my API  and bam! error 500.  After a bunch of reading I see similar issues regarding AspNetCoreModule vs AspNetCoreModuleV2 and some issues with InProcess vs OutOfProcess.

I then deployed right from VS and amazingly everything worked.  I can't do that EVERY time so went back to pipeline deploy and bam error 500 again.

"Detailed Error Information:
Module     AspNetCoreModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    aspNetCore
Error Code     0x00000000"

Answer (score 0):

And My Answer!

After comparing the output files from VS deploy and what's in the deploy artifact I realized my .xml comment files were missing in the artifact,  the same comments used by swagger....  UGH...

Solution: Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer - Lesson Learned!